# Playstore Android Pre-Launch Test FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger

Tags: java, android

on google developer console during pre-launch test I am getting the 40% of time this exception when they test with Samsung Galaxy S9, but I am going crazy since 2 day now without finding anything.

Could please someone help me?

```
03-04 12:10:20.274: E/Finsky(23969): --------- beginning of crash
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164): FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164): Process: com.betmines, PID: 26164
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'boolean android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.mSealed' on a null object reference
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164):    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.init(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:3223)
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164):    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.obtain(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:3051)
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164):    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.uiautomator.UiAutomatorStateExtractor.getAccessibilityHierarchy(UiAutomatorStateExtractor.java:24)
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164):    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridStateExtractor.getAccessibilityHierarchy(HybridStateExtractor.java:30)
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164):    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.handleTakeScreenshot(RemotePlatform.java:51)
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164):    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.access$500(RemotePlatform.java:93)
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164):    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform$ControllerMessageHandler.handleMessage(RemotePlatform.java:12)
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
03-04 12:10:20.300: E/AndroidRuntime(26164):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
```

Thanks in advance to anyone can help.

Regards...

Comment: Check out the logcat logs within Pre-Launch for that report and search for ** NullPointerException** to see what the logs look like. When I searched logcat for a pre-launch report that was failing with the same error, it looked like it hit that error while loading some of its own instrumentation tools, which would imply this is an issue with Google's code not ours. This would not be the first time that the pre-launch reports run into weird errors that are not actually caused by our code.

Comment: thank you @hvaughan3 , I checked out the logcat logs and I do not see much more than I've  in the stack trace I've posted. But as you said it looks like that could be related to some of their instrumentation tools. I can see androidx.test.tools.crawler... So let's hope is this and thank you again.

Comment: This is on Google's side. They are having issues with pre-launch reports right now. You should have a message at the top of the pre-launch report page.

Comment: thank you @nab. I don't have that message but I really think it's something on google side.

Comment: I received the same exception today. Considering the post is two days old, I take it as Google having issues with PLR right now.

Answer (score 8):

As others suggested, Google is experiencing issues with pre-launch tests. The only thing you can do now is filter the crashes to see if there is any of your code in there, but most likely it's just a couple of Google's false positives.

There was also this message on the console:

[image]

Basically, all good. Enjoy your release day. :)